# Linux Mint Backgrounds Setting Not Doing Anything

Tags: wallpaper

I  am running Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.3 64 bit. The desktop background is the default one, however, when I click on "Backgrounds" in the system settings, nothing happens. However, I can set the desktop background by right clicking the image and clicking set background. Any help is appreciated.

[image]

[image]